# Images and text are not showing on the front-end on products in laravel-voyager

Tags: php, laravel

i have created a model product on laravel-voyager using dummy section and laravel-voyager and i have created product section and used the bread system but when i tried to put the data to the front end the images text are not showing please help
how to create product section and how to used for front end i have created a put images the text are not showing on the post there are showing and i'm beginner on laravel-voyager

i have tried the product i have type the code correctly and also data is showing on front end but images text price are not showing on the page

```
<div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 row-fluid float-left p-0">
@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pl-0 pr-0 pb-4 float-left">
<div class="products-list__item p-2 lightgrey_borders">
<form method="post" class="pr-2 pl-2" action="/product/{{ $product->id }}">
<button class="float-right add_to_wishlist" type="submit"><i data-id="49872" class="icon-herz wishlist rose-highlight"></i></button>
<div class="products-list__image">
<a href="{{ $product->id }}"><img alt="" src=Voyager::image{{$product->image}}" width="50px"></a>
</div>
<h4 class="delta products-list__title"><a href="#"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"></font></font></a></h4>
<hr class="rule">
<div class="products-list__footer">
<span class="products-list__price"><small>
  <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">only</font>
</font>
</small>
<font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">$ {{$product->price}}</font>
</font>
</span>
</div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pl-0 pr-0 pb-4 float-left">
</div>

</section>
</section>
```

images,text and price is not showing

Comment: You're missing a quote on the src, but shouldn't it be `src="{{Voyager::image($product->image)}}"` ?

Comment: okay i got it i'm beginner on laravel-voyager

Comment: still not working need to put some code for the for work on product model

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Product extends Model
{

}